# kubctl run vs a job when using stdin/stderr/stdout

Tags: kubernetes

What is better to use for running some time limited operation on a new pod:

1. `kubectl run` to create a pod
2. Create a regultar Kubernetes job, with e.g. `kubectl apply -f job.yaml`

Requisites:

I have two use cases:

1. I must pass via `stdin` binary content to the pod.  With `kubectl run -i` this is trivial and it works.  With a job I don't know how to do it.
2. I must get via `stdout` binary content from the pod, and from `stderr` log output.  With `kubectl run --attach` this is trivial also, and it works.  With a job I could use `kubectl logs`, but don't know how to separate `stdin` from `stderr`.

Do I get better scalability or any other advantage (recovering from errors) by using a job, instead of a pod?

Comment: I wonder if your use case would be better met by having a long-running container that you could HTTP POST the data to.  Kubernetes Pods are long-running more often than not and typically intended to be restartable, and as you note it can be tricky to interact with their stdin/stdout.

Comment: it can be done, but it is more complicate to code

Answer (score 0):

For the `stdout` case, I've managed to use a `job`.

The pod of the job, does a `kubectl cp` to the calling pod and transfers all the needed files.

In this way, I don't need to use a stdout, and I can specify limnits of resources.

The advantage is that autoscaling of nodes DOES work.